# Get image mode PIL Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, blending

I am trying to blend two images together but I keep getting an error that one of the images in in the wrong mode. I tried to convert this image but every mode I have tried just makes the entire image white. Is there a way in Python with the PIL module to find out what the current image mode is?

```
Image.blend(img ,im ,0.05)
```

Error message:
`ValueError: image has wrong mode`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See the [Image Attributes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.mode) in the documentation:

> `Image.mode`: `str`
>
> Image mode. This is a string specifying the pixel format used by the image. Typical values are `'1'`, `'L'`, `'RGB'`, or `'CMYK'`. See [Modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) for a full list.

The [**`Image.convert`**](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) method creates, from an existing image, a new `Image` with a given `mode`.

Comment: The links for image attributes and concepts are now dead.

Comment: @IhateJS I fixed the links.